# Parsing JSON in Python (Reverse dictionary search)

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm using Python and "requests" to practice the use of API. I've had success with basic requests and parsing, but having difficulty with list comprehension for a more complex project.

I requested from a server and got a dictionary. From there, I used:

```
participant_search = (match1_request['participantIdentities'])
```

To convert the values of the participantIdentities key to get the following data:

```
[{'player': 
{'summonerName': 'Crescent Bladex',
'matchHistoryUri': '/v1/stats/player_history/NA1/226413119',
'summonerId': 63523774,
'profileIcon': 870},
'participantId': 1},
```

My goal here is to combine the summonerId and participantId to one list. Which is easy normally, but the order of ParticipantIdentities is randomized. So the player I want information on will sometimes be 1st on the list, and other times third.

So I can't use the `var = list[0]` like how I would normally do.

I have access to summonerId, so I'm thinking I can search the list the summonerId, then somehow collect all the information around it. For instance, if I knew `63523774` then I could find the key for it. From here, is it possible to find the parent list of the key?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Edit (Clarification):

Here's the data I'm working with: http://pastebin.com/spHk8VP0

At line 1691 is where participant the nested dictionary 'participantIdentities' is. From here, there are 10 dictionaries. These 10 dictionaries include two nested dictionaries, "player" and "participantId".

My goal is to search these 10 dictionaries for the one dictionary that has the summonerId. The summonerId is something I already know before I make this request to the server.

So I'm looking for some sort of "search" method, that goes beyond "true/false". A search method that, if a value is found within an object, the entire dictionary (key:value) is given.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the desired output (along with a more complete sample of input you have already partially included)

Comment: Sorry jeff, i modified my OP for clarity

Comment: Are you really asking "how do i get the stats for a given summoner?"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I properly understood you, but would this work?

```
for i in range(len(match1_request['participantIdentities'])):
    if(match1_request['participantIdentities'][i]['summonerid'] == '63523774':
       # do whatever you want with it.
```

`i` becomes the index you're searching for.

Comment: This is the data I'm working with: http://pastebin.com/spHk8VP0 I'm trying to create a dictionary out of participant identities for the nested dictionary with the desired summonerId

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dict comprehension to build a dict wich uses `summonerId`s as keys:

```
players_list = response['participantIdentities']
{p['player']['summonerId']: p['participantId'] for p in players_list}
```

Comment: This is brilliant. This really simplifies the data. From here, how would I code it so, based on the summoner id, the participant id is returned? I'll give `44610089` to the program, it spits out 2, basically. How would I do that?

Comment: edit: thanks, i realized the answer is easy. print(var[key]). The difficult part was organizing it so the "search item" was a key in a dictionary.

Comment: I've tried cleaning up the code, but ran into this, `p['participantIdentities']['player']['summonerId']: p['participantIdentities']['participantId'] for p in match1_request}
TypeError: string indices must be integers` any clue?

Comment: Sorry for spam. Is your suggestion for list comprehension only? Do dictionaries require for loops to be comprehended?

Comment: Updated my answer @JohnSeuss I'm not sure what you mean with for loops for being comprehended... Maybe this might help? http://www.diveintopython3.net/comprehensions.html#listcomprehension

Answer (score 0):

```
ds = match1_request['participantIdentities']
result_ = [d for d in ds if d["player"]["summonerId"] == 12345]
result = result_[0] if result_ else {}
```

See if it works for you.

Comment: Works great! Okay, so now that I know the ParticipantId of the player, I ran into another problem. There are 10 "stats" dictionaries... They have the same name. How do I choose the 2nd one? http://pastebin.com/spHk8VP0 see line 220, 391, 558... for examples. Line 391 is the 2nd stat dictionary I want. Normally this is easy.. but they have the same name...

Comment: @JohnSeuss It's a  really big file. see if it works `stats = [p["stats"] for p in result["participants"]]`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for is: "How do I get the stats for a given a summoner?"

You'll need a mapping of `participantId` to `summonerId`.

For example, would it be helpful to know this?

```
summoner[1] = 63523774
summoner[2] = 44610089
...
```

If so, then:

```
# This is probably what you are asking for:
summoner = {ident['participantId']: ident['player']['summonerId'] 
            for ident in match1_request['participantIdentities']}

# Then you can do this:
summoner_stats = {summoner[p['participantId']]: p['stats']
                  for p in match1_request['participants']}

# And to lookup a particular summoner's stats:
print summoner_stats[44610089]
```

(ref: [raw data](http://pastebin.com/raw/spHk8VP0) you pasted)